# Getting certain elements from arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, element

I have a variable called calculation, whose data is shown below. Ignoring the first array, which only consists of one value, the second and third arrays have 3 elements inside of them.

I'm trying to access and use to make a plot certain values from this calculation variable corresponding to the 2nd array (out of the 3) but only the first elements within that 2nd array. How would I code a variable to get these elements from my calculation variable?

For example, I've tried print(calculation[1]), which gives that entire 2nd array. I've also tried print(calculation[1][0]) to try and get the 0th elements from the 2nd array, but this yields only the first array from that entire 2nd array.

Doing print(calculation) yields:

```
(array(86391360), array([[[-4.48794000e+05,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.49597420e+11,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[-4.48793336e+05, -7.72416000e+06,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.49597199e+11,  2.57472000e+08,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[-4.48791343e+05, -1.54483200e+07,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.49596535e+11,  5.14943216e+08,  0.00000000e+00]],

       ...,

       [[ 5.07357741e+05, -7.72182336e+10,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-1.68852984e+11, -6.29442198e+10,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 5.07420359e+05, -7.72259563e+10,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-1.68873839e+11, -6.31851333e+10,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 5.07481946e+05, -7.72336789e+10,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-1.68894351e+11, -6.34260754e+10,  0.00000000e+00]]]), array([[[ 0.00000000e+00, -8.94000000e+02,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  2.98000000e+04,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 1.53782948e-04, -8.94000000e+02,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-5.12180648e+01,  2.97999546e+04,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 3.07565355e-04, -8.93999999e+02,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-1.02435950e+02,  2.97998184e+04,  0.00000000e+00]],

       ...,

       [[ 7.30723767e-03, -8.93826810e+02,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-2.43370658e+03, -2.78818274e+04,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 7.18780521e-03, -8.93826800e+02,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-2.39392910e+03, -2.78851623e+04,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 7.06836086e-03, -8.93826790e+02,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-2.35414765e+03, -2.78884422e+04,  0.00000000e+00]]]))
```

Thanks for any support!

Comment: Why did you stop after `[1][0]`? You just need to index one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Calling your second array `A`:

```
A = calculation[1]
```

`A` has three dimensions (which we can see from the triple levels of square braces `[`).  Let's call the dimensions "columns", "rows", and "pages".

To extract the first three-element row of `A` on the first page:

```
row0 = A[0,0,:]    # page 0, row 0, all columns
```

To extract the first two-element column of `A` on the first page:

```
col0 = A[0,:,0]    # page 0, all rows, column 0
```

To extract the corner element [0,0] from all pages:

```
corner0 = A[:,0,0]    # all pages, row 0, column 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AbbeGijly's response, I was able to get what i needed using this for loop, just in case anyone else stumbles upon this and finds it useful.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    col = A[i,:,0]
    print(col)
```